# Getx HttpClient is not working, I have tried everything thats on the internet

Tags: flutter, dart, httpclient, flutter-getx

I have implemented custom configurations for network call using getx getconnect in provider class but it is not working as intended. Also i have checked using debugging it is initialising provider class but not setting baseUrl and auth token etc. in provider class. I have also called it in binding class and in binding it is on top of all the controllers.

provider init code :

```
httpClient.baseUrl = "https://myUrl";
httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";
httpClient.timeout = Duration(seconds: 100);
httpClient.addResponseModifier((request, response) async {
  print(response.body);
});
httpClient.addRequestModifier<dynamic>((request) async {
  // add request here
  return request;
});


var headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer $token"};
httpClient.addAuthenticator<dynamic>((request) async {
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  return request;
});




class DataBinding extends Bindings{
    @override
    void dependencies() {
        Get.put(Provider());
        Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => LocationController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => ServicesController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => ConfirmRideController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => HomeController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => HelperController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => UserCardController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => ProfileController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => RequestController(), fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => TripController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => VoucherController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => InvoiceController(),fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut(() => HelpController(),fenix: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the full code of your provider class?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this;

```
httpClient.addResponseModifier((request, response) async {
  print(response.body);
  return response; // add this
});
```